# display filled field as empty field mysql view

Tags: mysql, view

How can I display as view a filled field as empty field in mysql?
It's about the field klanten.KlantEmail

thanks in advance

```
SELECT
klanten.KlantId,
klanten.KlantRelid,
klanten.KlantU4relid,
klanten.KlantZoeknaam,
klanten.KlantNaam,
klanten.KlantStraat,
klanten.KlantHuisnummer,
klanten.KlantAdres,
klanten.KlantPostcode,
klanten.KlantPlaats,
klanten.KlantPostbus,
klanten.KlantEmail
FROM
klanten
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this `SELECT "" as KlantEmail`

Comment: Are you saying that you want to output the column for `klantEmail` but you want it to always be an empty string

Comment: I found it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you would do this, assuming you want to output the column but have it as a empty string regardless or what is really in the column

```
SELECT
klanten.KlantId,
klanten.KlantRelid,
klanten.KlantU4relid,
klanten.KlantZoeknaam,
klanten.KlantNaam,
klanten.KlantStraat,
klanten.KlantHuisnummer,
klanten.KlantAdres,
klanten.KlantPostcode,
klanten.KlantPlaats,
klanten.KlantPostbus,
"" as klanten.KlantEmail
FROM
klanten
```